# Git: How to find commits with given Change-Id?

Tags: git, gerrit

Gerrit automatically adds a `Change-Id: I....` line in commit message for every new commits. When a commit is cherry-picked into multiple branches this line is preserved in its message.

Is there any way to:

1. find all commits with given Change-Id
2. find the commit on a specific branch with given Change-Id
3. specify the commit with given Change-Id (on a specific branch) as revision parameter(e.g. `git cherry-pick {[dev-branch::]Change-Id: Ixxxx}..master`)

Comment: `git log --grep=` should deal with 2. what would you do if you got multiple commits with the same change id in 3?

Comment: even if you updated 3, it makes the problem complicated enough that requires a more sophisticated decision procedure. i don't think you can do it without wrapping it inside of a script.

Comment: `ssh -p <port> <user>@<gerrithost> gerrit query change:<id>`. The port is 29418 by default. You could add other `<key>:<value>`, for example `branch:master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After I posted this answer, @lz96 suggested this:

```
git --no-pager log --format=format:%H -1 --grep "Change-Id: $1"
```

It's definitely the cleanest way!

---

Here's my original answer:

I can't think of a clean way of how to do it in one step, so here's two:

```
git log --grep "Change-Id: <id>"
```

This will show you all commits that have this `Change-Id` parameter. Step 1b: Pray it is only one.

Step 2: `git cherry-pick <sha>`.

---

Here's my ugly one-stepper:

```
git cherry-pick $(git log --grep "Change-Id: <id>" | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

You could probably make this into a function to hide all that complexity away:

```
function changepick() {
  git cherry-pick $(git log --grep "Change-Id: $1" | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
}
```

That also gives you the benefit of not having to insert the `Change-Id` halfway along a line.

Comment: `git --no-pager log --format=format:%H -1 --grep "Change-Id: $1"` might be better?

Comment: Yup, that is better!